# how to make paging in uitableview with call api ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

how to make paging(**load more data like facebook**) in UITableView with call api? 
Code:-

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat height = scrollView.frame.size.height;

    CGFloat contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    CGFloat distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset;

    if(distanceFromBottom < height)
    {

        [self fetchNewsFeeds:[filteredArray count]+1 withLimit:20];

        NSLog(@"end of the table");
    }
}
```

scroll upto the content height after not call api

Comment: Search for: "load more and lazy loading with table view"

Comment: What problem you are feeling actually?@Bhavesh Rathod

Comment: https://github.com/MrAlek/AWPagedArray , it will give you whole stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Store response data in a NSArray and then add to a NSMutableArray

```
NSArray *resObj = [NSArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *aMutArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[aMutArray addObject: resObj];
```

//check for last index of tableview
 write this code in cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
 if(lastIndex)
    {
         // show load more button
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take Two Sections : The rows in the first section contains items which you want to display and the second section contains one row whose cell has a `UIActivityIndicator`.

Then implement the given delegate method :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.section ==  1 {

        let footercell = cell as! ProductFooterCollectionViewCell
        footercell.loader.startAnimating()
        fetchSearchProducts()
     }             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tableview Delegate when display cell this method call:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger totalRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];//first get total rows in that section by current indexPath.
    if(indexPath.row == totalRow-1)
    {
        // Code...
    }
}
```

Hope your problem solve.

Comment: i used this solution but my code run like loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find last row of your **tableviewcell**.

Below is the code for finding last row:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSInteger totalNumberOfRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];

// isLoadMore flage is TRUE when there is more data available.
        if(indexPath.row == totalNumberOfRows-1 && isLoadMore)
        {
            // Code...
            // Here you need to check if there are some load more data is there from pervious web-service or not.
    // If there is load more then call web-service and another set of data.
        }
    }
```

You can use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to get call your web-service.

Hope you get logic :)

Comment: i used this solution but my code run like loop

Comment: You need to put check, if there is no more data for load more, then set a flage and check condition in weillDisplayCell method.  Check my updated condition.